# Close popup with key Esc

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube

I try to close popup when I press <kbd>Esc</kbd> but it only works while video isn't on play.

```
$(document).bind('keydown', function (e) {
    if(e.which === 27){
        $('#youmax-video-lightbox').attr('src', '');
        $('#youmax-lightbox').hide();
    }
});
```

U can see in:
http://www.vigerm.com/videos

Comment: have you include the jquery library file?

Comment: Yes ^^, it works if video is not playing :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because when the user clicks on play to start the video, the flash object gets the focus and the document does not receive anymore the input events.
Not sure what you can do about it. Maybe auto-play the videos when opening the pop-up?

Answer (score 0):

It has nothing to do with whether or not the video is playing.  If you open the video without clicking anything else, `Esc` still closes it fine.  It's when you click the video, events no longer bubble up to the document, so your handler is never called.  You need to either stop the video from stopping event propagation or attach handlers to the video element itself as well.